# How to include the icon inside the tooltip message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I need to include the download icon inside the tooltip message, I have tried the below code:

```
ObjectIconView: Ember.ContainerView.extend(childMOMixin, {
                iconDownload: function () {
                              model: 'download'
                },
                mouseEnter: function(e) {
                if(type == 'Text'){
                var textUrl = {content: 'Preview is Not Available, Use '+ this.iconDownload() +'Menu'};
                this.$().tooltip(textUrl);
}
}
```

In that I have called the `iconDownload` inside the tooltip. But it's saying `undefined` in the output. I'm using Ember 1.4.0 version. Can anybody please provide the suggestion for this. I'm new to the Ember. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code at line 2. ``function () { model: 'download' }` is not valid JavaScript. Also it would be helpful if you could include what library provides `$().tooltip()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that you need to change to get the tooltip to display the data you're expecting.

1:  Return something from `iconDownload`
Right now, the function returns nothing, it makes an internal list and then does nothing.
Does it even need to be a function, or could it just be a string, object?

2:  You're not accessing the data in it correctly.
Assuming you're actually needing a hash returned, you're not accessing the data properly - all you're doing is getting the object.
With the structure you have right now, you'r string generator would be 
`'Preview is Not Available, Use '+ this.iconDownload().model +'Menu'`

---

I'd recommend a couple of additional changes, if they're possible.

1:  Use the Ember getter to get data from iconDownload.
Instead of this.iconDownload, call `this.get('iconDownload.model')` or `this.get('iconDownload')`

2: Make the actual tooltip text a computed property.

```
toolTipText: function () {
    return `Preview is Not Available, Use ${this.get('iconDownload.model')} Menu`;
}.property('iconDownload.model');
```

Now, you can just call this.get('toolTipText') to get what the tooltip says.

3: Move your mouseEnter function into the actions section of your view's javascript